# Explore an Array in GWT without knowing its type

Tags: java, arrays, gwt, reflection

I am building a generic visualizer of objects with GWT. For this, I am using the reflection capabilities offered by [gwt-ent](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-ent/). With it I can explore methods and fields and that's enough for classes. One problem I still have is that gwt-ent does not allow me to explore arrays. It gives me the type of its components, but not a get() or a set() method, as java.lang.reflection.Array does.

So I have used the native java.lang.reflection.Array, which curiously works when in debug mode (how is that possible?), but when I go into production mode the compiler complains.

I have tried some tricks, for instance by converting the array to an ArrayList with java.utils.Array.asList(T... a) but there's not way for making it work. I have seen a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972709/creating-new-array-with-class-object-in-gwt). In that case one of the suggestion was to import the JSNI method provided byt com.google.gwt.lang.Array.createFrom(..), but I can see in [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.6.0/com/google/gwt/lang/Array.java) that this class unfortunately has a set() method but no get() method !

The question is: do you see any way for accessing an element of an array without knowing the type of the array in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is not supported in GWT compiled. It can work in dev-mode because most of the code when debugging is run in JVM instead of browser.

I suggest, to modify the gwt-ent generator to match your requirements and send a patch to the author with your contribution, or maybe change gwt-ent by other 3party library like gwt-reflector.

Another interesting gwt reflection project I've found is [gwt-processor](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-preprocessor/wiki/HowTo) it seems not to use generators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know the gwt-reflector library, I will try it, but as far as I can see, it does not support exploring arrays either :(

Comment: Right it does not support arrays, I thought it did. So you have to implement that feature someway.

Comment: actually I cannot even explore lists, nor methods. In general it's much more limited than gwt-ent, which is a pity, because I liked gwt-reflector being lightweight. I am not that good in GWT to program the missing feature myself, but, if explained a bit I could help.

Comment: Maybe you can contact with the author, I guess he is going to help you. Normally we (opensource developers) like users feedback and contributions. Also found another reflection project edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Manolo, actually I am in contact with the developers of GWT-reflector, and they are already helping me (see [the issues tracker](https://github.com/sykesd/gwt-reflector/issues?state=open)). For the moment there is no support for arrays, but there are ways to explore lists.